# Save offline data from Website running javascript

Tags: php

I'm new at php so maybe this question looks dull but i hope everybody can help me.
This is original [link](http://www.nowgoal.com/analysis/1420608.html)

I want to get data from Odds Column as attached picture

[image: cat]

When i Choose Crow or Sbobet or Bet365...  data of Odds Column will change. I want to collect data of each column and put it into an different array.
I actually don't need a code, just need a solution or recommendation. Thank guys for reading my question.

Comment: It depends on how this table is created. For that you've included no code. However, from a pseudo-code point of view: You can initialize a new array. Then you can put the data for just the Odds Column in a for each loop and inside the loop, you can push each value into that array you created. If you provide some code,someone else or I could help you more.

Comment: thanks alot for help ;)